# How to update individual JSON field in mongoDb from Springboot

Tags: json, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to update the value of a single field of a stored JSON in MongoDb from `Springboot`. I'm not using `POJO` since the `JSON` schema will be random always.

```
// this is what I'm trying to achieve. But I don't know how to do it from SpringBoot.
    db.collection.update(  { _id:12345} , { $set: { a.b.c.d : updatedValue  } }
```

This is how I saved my `JSON` Object to `MongoDB`:

```
    Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
    DB db = mongo.getDB("dbOne");
    DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("data");

    // convert JSON to DBObject directly
    DBObject dbObject = (DBObject) JSON.parse(jsonString);

    collection.insert(dbObject);
```

My `JSON` sample data:

```
    {
        "a":{
            "b":{
                "c":{
                    "d":"value1",
                    "e":"value2"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do it via mongoOperations and Update [API](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Update.html).
This will allow you to update individual fields in a mongodb collection-
Ex:

```
Query query = new Query(new Criteria("id").is(12345L));
Update updateOp = new Update().set("a.b.c.d", value);
mongoOperations.updateFirst(query, updateOp, COLLECTION);
```